# Change the language of the Paypal confirmation Email

Tags: api, email, localization, paypal

Is it possible to change the language of the confirmation email (This is the email you get when a payment has been successful). The default language is set in your paypal account settings. We make payments with the mass payment api (classic) to people from different countries. We would like them to receive an email in their own language. So we want to set the language per request. Is this at all possible?

Cheers,
Paul